How to store an optimizer in a struct field without type inference with Burn?
Looking at the Burn book about custom training loops. The Custom Type section has some examples. I also found the example code.
What is a full example of using those structs to store the optimizer? I can't find a way to do that. I either run into an error about setting the Record type, or it can't match the type parameter because the init method returns an opaque type.
Here's an example. This gives an error on the call to make_learner.
use burn::{backend::{wgpu::AutoGraphicsApi, Autodiff, Wgpu}, module::Module, nn::{Linear, LinearConfig}, optim::{AdamWConfig, Optimizer}, tensor::backend::{AutodiffBackend, Backend}};

type TheBackend = Wgpu<AutoGraphicsApi, f32, i32>;
type TheAutodiffBackend = Autodiff<TheBackend>;

#[derive(Module, Debug)]
struct Model<B:Backend> {
    layer: Linear<B>,
}


fn main() {
    let device = burn::backend::wgpu::WgpuDevice::default();
    // Error on the following line
    make_learner::<TheBackend,Optimizer<Model<TheBackend>,TheBackend>>(&device);
}

struct Learner1<B, O>
where
    B: AutodiffBackend,
{
    model: Model<B>,
    optim: O,
}

pub fn make_learner<B,O>(device: &B::Device) -> Learner1<B, impl Optimizer<Model<B>, B>>
where
    B: AutodiffBackend,
    O: Optimizer<Model<B>, B>,
{
    let model = Model {
        layer: LinearConfig::new(10, 10).init(device),
    };
    // Optimizer<Model<B>, B>
    // let optim = AdamW::new(AdamWConfig::default(), model.parameters());
    let optim = AdamWConfig::new().init::<B,Model<B>>();
    Learner1 { model, optim }
}

impl<B, O> Learner1<B, O>
where
    B: AutodiffBackend,
    O: Optimizer<Model<B>, B>,
{
}


I asked on discord and was directed to this PR:
Replace opaque return types in optim
With a concrete type being returned, that resolves the issue. At the time I tried it, that PR had not been released yet. I had to depend on the source directly to get the latest code from the main branch.
